# How to fetch data from dynamically created input textboxes on click of save button in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I'm dynamically creating textboxes and save button for each Item and on click of save button I need to fetch value from the text box of that particular item.

```
 for (let d = 0; d <= ItemsInfo.length - 1; d++)
    {                 
           content += '<tr>  <td> <label for="lblPriority">Item Priority </label>  </td>  ';
           content += ' <td>   <input type="text" id="inpItemPRIORITY" ng-model="prty" value=" ' +  ItemsInfo[d].PRIORITY  + ' " /> </td> </tr>';
           content += '<tr>  <td>  <label for="lblItemComment">Item Comment</label></td> ';
           content += ' <td>   <input type="text" id="inpItemCOMMENT"  ng-model="cmnt"  value=" ' + ItemsInfo[d].COMMENT + ' " /> </td> </tr>';
            // Save Item
          content += '<tr>  <td>  <button class="get-data" ng-click="buttonClick(prty,cmnt)">Save Item(' + ItemsInfo[d].ITEM_ID + ')</button> </td> </tr> ';
  }
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.buttonClick = function (prty,cmnt) {
  console.log(prty + " " + cmnt); } // console.log displays as undefined undefined
```

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Of course, using the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive

Comment: To expand on @AlonEitan correct comment: Instead of a `for` loop, use the ngRepeat directive in the Angular template to create the checkboxes.  This will permit you to set up an [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) binding to your controller code.

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way. You might want to loop over ```ItemsInfo``` in your template using ```ngRepeat```. Here's a Codepen that'll show you how to use it if the documentation is not enough: https://codepen.io/Shokeen/pen/EWBdNM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a start, the proper AngularJs would be to use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directly in your HTML template, but i'm still giving you a solution with your current code:

First, an HTML id should be unique, you are looping manually on your array in the controller, so you can add an index number to the id, and give it to your function to find the elements (also fixed the for loop condition for optimisation):

In this case, it's useless to bind to a model, or else all inputs will use the same scope variable. This code also shows the proper way to retrieve a DOM element in jQlite format in AngularJS:

```
for (let d = 0; d < ItemsInfo.length; d++)
{                 
    content += '<tr>  <td> <label for="lblPriority">Item Priority </label>  </td>  ';
    content += ' <td>   <input type="text" id="inpItemPRIORITY_' + d + '" value="' +  ItemsInfo[d].PRIORITY  + '" /> </td> </tr>';
    content += '<tr>  <td>  <label for="lblItemComment">Item Comment</label></td> ';
    content += ' <td>   <input type="text" id="inpItemCOMMENT_' + d + '"  value="' + ItemsInfo[d].COMMENT + '" /> </td> </tr>';
    // Save Item
    content += '<tr>  <td>  <button class="get-data" ng-click="buttonClick(' + d + ')">Save Item(' + ItemsInfo[d].ITEM_ID + ')</button> </td> </tr> ';
}
```

```
$scope.buttonClick = function (index) {
    let prty = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#inpItemPRIORITY_' + index ) ),
        cmnt = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#inpItemCOMMENT_' + index ) );
    console.log(prty.val() + " " + cmnt.val());
};
```

Here a snippet that demonstrate. just an example to show that it works (EDIT: added `$compile` directive for `buttonClick` to work properly).

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
    
    const ItemsInfo = [
        { ITEM_ID: 'a1', COMMENT: 'comment a1', PRIORITY: 0 },
        { ITEM_ID: 'b1', COMMENT: 'comment b1', PRIORITY: 1 },
        { ITEM_ID: 'c1', COMMENT: 'comment c1', PRIORITY: 2 },
    ];
    
    let content = '';
    for (let d = 0; d < ItemsInfo.length; d++)
    {                 
        content += '<tr>  <td> <label for="lblPriority">Item Priority </label>  </td>  ';
        content += ' <td>   <input type="text" id="inpItemPRIORITY_' + d + '" value=" ' +  ItemsInfo[d].PRIORITY  + ' " /> </td> </tr>';
        content += '<tr>  <td>  <label for="lblItemComment">Item Comment</label></td> ';
        content += ' <td>   <input type="text" id="inpItemCOMMENT_' + d + '"  value=" ' + ItemsInfo[d].COMMENT + ' " /> </td> </tr>';
        // Save Item
        content += '<tr>  <td>  <button class="get-data" ng-click="buttonClick(' + d + ')">Save Item(' + ItemsInfo[d].ITEM_ID + ')</button> </td> </tr> ';
    }
    $scope.htmlContent = content;
    
    $scope.buttonClick = function (index) {
        let prty = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#inpItemPRIORITY_' + index ) ),
            cmnt = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#inpItemCOMMENT_' + index ) );
        console.log(prty.val() + " " + cmnt.val());
    };

  }])
  .directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
            }, function (value) {
                element.html(value);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table bind-html-compile="htmlContent"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but In my condition if data available I need to display some Item related content if not need to hide other Item related content. Using ngRepeat I'm unable to check the conditions to check data so creating text boxes dynamically.

Comment: After the changes as per your code I'm getting msg in console.log as   [[object HTMLInputElement]]

Comment: Yes and with .value() getting error msg as TypeError: cmnt.value is not a function.

Comment: console.log(cmnt.value ); --> undefined

Comment: You can call me stupid, forgetting my basics, it's `.val()` and not `.value()` in jQuery. Try `val()` ;)

Comment: @user11130182 updated snippet with `$compile` so that button works